# Automatically add custom taxonomy when meta value gets to a set number or beyond

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy, post-meta

Is it possible to add a custom taxonomy to a post when a meta value gets to a set number?

Im trying to get it so once my `post_views_count` gets to 150+ it then gets the custom taxonomy `trending` added to it.

The only way i've found to do something similar to what i want to achieve is the  `add_action( 'save_post' );` hook. Which to my understanding only applies it at post save. which is useless as the `post_views_count` updated every time `update_post_meta` is updated.

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);

    if($count==''){

        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";

    }

    return $count.' Views';
}

function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}


function ViewPostsTrending( $classes ) {

    global $post;

    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($post->ID, $count_key, true);

     if ( $count > 150 ) {

          $classes[] = 'trending';

    }

     return $classes; 
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'ViewPostsTrending');`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option would be is to use your `getPostViews()` count and incorporate a system in there to append the `trending` term to the post once your counter hits 150.

### Here is our worksflow

- Get the post view count (*which you are already doing*)
- Compare the current count to the desired 150
- Use `wp_set_object_terms()` to append the `trending` term to the post

### IN CODE

(*I have modified your code slightly. Also note, the code is untested*)

```
function getPostViews()
{
    // Check if we are on a single page, bail out if not
    if ( !is_single() )
        return false;

    // Get the current post id
    $current_post_id = get_queried_object_id();

    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta( $current_post_id, $count_key, true );

    // Set up our function to set our term 'trending'
    if ( $count >= 150 ) {
        /**
         * First check if the term is not yet set, if not, set the term
         * I have used trending as term slug. Change as needed
         * Also, add the correct taxonomy to which trending term belongs to
         *
         * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term
         */
        if ( !has_term( 'trending', 'MY_TAX', $current_post_id ) ) {
            /**
             * Append the term trending to the post
             *
             * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms
             */
            wp_set_object_terms( 
                $current_post_id, // Current post ID
               'trending', // Slug of term to append
               'MY_TAX', // Taxonomy that the term trending belongs to
               true // VERY VERY IMPORTANT, Append the term to the other existing terms
            );
        }
    }

    if( !$count ){

        delete_post_meta( $current_post_id, $count_key );
        add_post_meta( $current_post_id, $count_key, '0' );

    }

    $views = ( $count ) ? $count . ' Views' : '0 View';
    return $views;

}
```

You can just simply use the code in your single page as follow

```
echo getPostViews();
```

and the function does the rest

Comment: Any feedback regarding this issue. Would like to hear if it worked or not :-)